tracking the history of data in bigquery
I have table (my_table) in bigquery (where i m not admin) whose values changes on daily basis:
i.e. my_table is some what:
item:    apple
quantiy: 20
tomorrow it could be:
item:    apple
quantiy: 10
and so on!
I want to track the history of the data lets say for coming 7 days.
at day 8 (counting from today)
i want to have 7 results in my table like:
item:    apple
quantiy: 20
date:    27.06.2024
item:    apple
quantiy: 10
date:    28.06.2024
item:    apple
quantiy: 20
date:    29.06.2024
.
.
.
item:    apple
quantiy: 20
date:    03.07.2024
anybody having any idea how to deal with this!!!!!

An approach that you can use is the BigQuery change history:
SELECT
  item,
  quantity,
  _CHANGE_TYPE AS change_type,
  _CHANGE_TIMESTAMP AS change_time
FROM
  APPENDS(TABLE mydataset.mytable, TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 DAY), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Note this feature is in preview and depends on table time travel window.
